# How we can call a public function inside public function using event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

```
<div id="a"></div><br>
<div id="b"></div>
<script>
    function Con(id){
        this.id = id;
        var me = this;

        x = function(){ // public function
            console.log(this.id)
        }.bind(this);

        this.y= function(){ // public function
            console.log(me)
            html = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='mycls-"+this.id+"' onclick='x()'>hello-"+this.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = html;
        }
        this.y();
    }
    var v = new Con("a");
    var v1 = new Con("b");
</script>
```

I have javascript constructor i want to call the x public function from a link which is inside of the  y public function.  I want to get the proper id EX: if I am click on the a div it should console a or if I am click on the b div it should console b but it always console only b.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but you do realize that "x" function is not public right now due to variable scope? If you want it to be public, it should be "this.x".

Comment: It only prints "b", because of line 3: var me = this; *this* points to the newly created object, so by storing it in a variable you will always get the latest instance (in this case "b")

Comment: If I am calling function like this.x() its giving error like: Uncaught TypeError: this.x is not a function(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pass the ID in the x function like a argument:
`onclick='x("+this.id+")'`

```
x = function(arg){ // public function
    console.log(arg.id)
}.bind(this);
```

Please find the total code:

```
<div id="a"></div><br>
<div id="b"></div>
<script>
    function Con(id){
        this.id = id;
        var me = this;
        x = function(arg){ // public function
            console.log(arg.id)
        }.bind(this);

        this.y= function(){ // public function
            html = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='mycls-"+this.id+"' onclick='x("+this.id+")'>hello-"+this.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = html;
        }
        this.y();
    }
    var v = new Con("a");
    var v1 = new Con("b");
</script>
```